# How to create a new formatted date from 2 dates using JavaScript or moment

Tags: javascript, momentjs

How to get new formatted date from 2 dates? For example, I have these dates: 
**03/12/2017** and **03/20/2017**.

The result that I want is: **March 12 - 20 , 2017**

Thank you for your suggestion and answers - it will help me a lot in my code problem now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let assume you have 2 moment objects m1 & m2 populated with your two dates

the following function will do the trick :

```
function format(m1, m2) {
    if (m1.isAfter(m2)) 
        return format(m2, m1)
    let result = moment.months()[m1.month()] + ' ' + m1.date() + ' '
    if (m1.year() !== m2.year())
        result += m1.year() + ' '
    result += '- '
    if (m1.month() !== m2.month() || m1.year() !== m2.year())
        result += moment.months()[m2.month()] + ' '
    result += m2.date() + ' ' + m2.year()
    return result
}
```